# Continuous function on unit disc with $({\text{Re}}(z))^3$ on boundary?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, analytic-functions

I'm trying to answer the following question:

*Let $D$ denote the open unit disc. Does there exist a continuous function $f:\overline{D}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ that is analytic on $D,$ and whose restriction to $\partial\overline{D}$ is the function $f|_{\partial\overline{D}}(z)=({\text{Re}}(z))^3$?*

My instinct is no. Supposing there were, I would like to use the [maximum/minimum] modulus principle to state that $|f|$ does not attain its [maximum/minimum] value within $D.$ Because $|f|$ on the boundary has maximum value $1$ and minimum value $0,$ this implies that $0<|f(z)|<1$ for all $z\in D.$ Are we then able to find some $z\in D$ that has $f(z)=0,$ obtaining a contradiction?

I'm a bit stuck. Any hint/guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The Fourier series of $f$ (on the unit circle) contains only positive  powers of $z$ if $f$ comes from an analytic function in the disc (think cauchy applied to $f(z)z^k, k \ge 0$); however $2\Re z= z+1/z$ on the unit circle so the cube contains negative powers of $z$ and that is a contradiction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|\operatorname{Im} f|$ attains its maximum on $\partial D$. But $|\operatorname{Im} f|=0$ on $\partial D$, hence $f$ takes on only real values and is therefore constant, a contradiction.
(To prove that $|\operatorname{Im} f|$ attains its maximum on $\partial D$ just copy the proof of the maximum modulus theorem using the open mapping theorem)

Comment: You can also argue that $\operatorname{Im} f$ is a *harmonic* function, and therefore attains both maximum and minimum on the boundary.

Comment: Let $v(z):=\operatorname{Im} f(z)$, then $\min\limits_{z\in\partial D}v(z)\leq v(z)\leq\max\limits_{z\in\partial D} v(z)$.

Comment: Your comments have helped. Thank you all!